# how to handle multiple switch from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am  many pages in my app some of them has appbar and some of them does not. So For that I have used for than one `switch` one is wrapped in MainContainer and other one is without any appBar. But the problem is one that i have wrapped doesnot show any content on the screen i don't know why.

Here is my code

> AuthLogin.jsx

```
render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <TempLogin />
        </Route>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/auth/:token"
          component={RoundLoadingWhileAuthenticating}
        />
        <MainContainer />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

> MainContainer.jsx

```
<div
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />   <-- this does not show anycontent
        
          <Route path="*" component={Error404Page} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try moving the `<MainContainer />` from the `authlogin.jsx` `<switch>` statement to just outside of it – so it isn't a child

Comment: Not getting it @MikeAbeln

Comment: in `authlogin.jsx` swap the lines containing `<MainContainer />` and `</Switch>` so that the MainContainer component is not a child of the switch statements. Currently you're nesting the switch statements inside one another through the component hierarchy and I think it's causing a conflict – you only get one match per `switch` statement, so you have to make them independent of each other